# Collapse leaflet control

Tags: leaflet

I want to collapse a leaflet control on my map.  I have the current code:

```
    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright', collapsed:true});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML = "<h6>DISCLAIMER:<br>text</h3><table></table>";
        return div;
    };
    legend.addTo(map);
```

But I still cannot get it to collapse or appear on hover like my layers selection does.  How do I need to adjust my code?  I have visited the Leaflet examples but it seems like the collapse feature is only for layer elements and not simply for a control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being the solution using HTML attributes of "onmousenenter" and "onmouseleave":

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    function showDisclaimer() {
        var div = document.getElementById("info legend")
        div.innerHTML = "<h6>DISCLAIMER:<br>text</h3><table></table>";
    }

    function hideDisclaimer() {
        var div = document.getElementById("info legend")
        div.innerHTML = "<h2>DISCLAIMER</h2>";
    }

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML = "<h2>DISCLAIMER</h2>";
    div.setAttribute("onmouseenter", "showDisclaimer()");
    div.setAttribute("onmouseleave", "hideDisclaimer()");
    div.id = "info legend"

        return div;
    };
    legend.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `collapsed:true` is going to make sense in this context, as there isn't a legend control in Leaflet that is analogous to the layer control (`L.control.layers`).

Similar to the layer control, you could construct a div with an icon that always shows by default, with the legend hidden by default, but positioned to hide the icon div when visible.

Then with javascript/jQuery, show the legend [on hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('#legend-icon-div).hover(
  function() {
    $('#legend').show();
  }, function() {
    $('#legend').hide();
  }
)
```

Comment: yeah I didn't think collapsed:true could apply to the control but I wasn't sure.  would I replace my code entirely with yours?

Comment: no, this isn't a complete solution, if I get time, I'll try to add more details. You'll need css and html for the 'icon div' at least. You could implement a custom Leaflet control for this, a bit more complicated, but tidier and more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of it, [Leaflet.EasyButton](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton) could help. It has a `disable` method that you can style to fit your needs ([example](http://danielmontague.com/projects/easyButton.js/v1/examples/#fancier-disable)).

in your js:

```
var disclaimer = L.easyButton('<h1>!!!</h1>', function(btn, map){
   alert('disclaimer here!!!');
},{position:'bottomright'});

disclaimer.addTo(map);
```

and in your css:

```
.easy-button-button.disabled{
  display: none;
}
```

then whenever you want, call:

```
disclaimer.disable();
// and
disclaimer.enable();
```